# How to override others dependencies in composer.json

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.6

I'm using [AliceFixturesBundles](https://github.com/h4cc/AliceFixturesBundle) and this depends on [NelmioAlice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice) and [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker). Dependencies are handled internal as for example:

```
https://github.com/h4cc/AliceFixturesBundle/blob/master/composer.json

{
    "name": "h4cc/alice-fixtures-bundle",
    "description": "Symfony2 Bundle for loading fixture data with the Alice library.",
    "keywords": ["Symfony2", "Fixtures", "Alice", "Loader", "Doctrine", "ORM", "MongoDB"],
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Julius Beckmann",
            "email": "github@h4cc.de"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "nelmio/alice": "~1.6",
        "doctrine/common": "~2.1",
        "psr/log": "~1.0",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.1",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "matthiasnoback/symfony-config-test": "~0.2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "h4cc\\AliceFixturesBundle\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

relies on:

```
https://github.com/nelmio/alice/blob/master/composer.json

{
    "name": "nelmio/alice",
    "description": "Expressive fixtures generator",
    "keywords": ["fixture", "data", "test", "orm"],
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jordi Boggiano",
            "email": "j.boggiano@seld.be"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tim Shelburne",
            "email": "shelburt02@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/common": "~2.3",
        "symfony/property-access": "~2.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Nelmio\\Alice\\": "src/Nelmio/Alice" }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.0.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

And my problem is just here, on this line: `"fzaninotto/faker": "~1.0",`, how do override that line on my `composer.json` in order to use `"fzaninotto/faker": "1.5.*@dev"` instead of the one defined?

Comment: Why do you want to override it?

Comment: @JamesSpence because I need to use something not tagged yet on Faker repo and it's only available at dev/master branch

Comment: hm I see. It looks like such behavior is possible. See [this link on overriding dependencies.](http://mnapoli.fr/overriding-dependencies-with-composer/)

Comment: A warning though: Overriding the dependency might have adverse effects on your other dependency (the one requiring the overridden dependency).

Comment: @JamesSpence I have already check that link before but not get how to do it on my environment can you provide an answer with the solution?

Comment: Answer posted below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your own composer.json, you can do this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "h4cc/alice-fixtures-bundle": "dev/master", //Whatever version you use
        "fzaninotto/faker": "dev-master as 1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, first got this `Invalid version string "~1.0" in "1.5.*@dev as ~1.0", the alias must be an exact version` then change the line from yours to this `"fzaninotto/faker": "1.5.*@dev as 1.0.0",` but then  I got this `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` I will ask package mantainer to see how I can deal with this, thanks'

Comment: It seems like your version specification (`1.5.*@dev`) might not be accurate. Try `dev-master`, see if that works.

Comment: No problem. Updated answer to reflect changes.